# Probability of end node Decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, cart

I'm having trouble finding the probability of the CART decision trees. I'll use that first CART as an example,

http://trevorstephens.com/kaggle-titanic-tutorial/r-part-3-decision-trees/
[image]

I want to know, given a female and a male the probability that they will die. So we have a CART constructed to classify. To find the probability that given a male person he will die, we would do: probability that he is male 0.62 (from the root node) times the probability that he dies 0.81 (left leaf). Is this correct?

So 0.62*0.81 would be the probability of a random male dying? Or would the probability that a male dies the 0.81?

Comment: Please give us more details and make your question self-contained.

Comment: @Tim edited and i think now it's more clear to what i'm asking